# Word VBA: ShapeRange.Delete unexpected behavior

Tags: vba, ms-word

**The Background**
This is closely related to the question [ms word 2010 macro How to select all shapes on a specific page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710959/ms-word-2010-macro-how-to-select-all-shapes-on-a-specific-page). But this concerns an unexpected result I'm getting from `ShapeRange.Delete`, when trying to code an answer for that question.

**The Question**
So, to set up the question. I'm able to change properties of the first and last shape on each page. However, when I replace the statement that changes the shape property (`shp.Range.ShapeRange.Line.Weight = 10`) with a statement that deletes the shape (`shp.Range.ShapeRange.Delete`), shapes are deleted that do not correspond to the shapes that had the property changed. *Why does `.Delete` not act on the same shapes as `.Line.Weight`?*

**Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place?**
There are a few strange things happening here. I'm working on a 2007 Word .docm document with macros enabled. The document is 9 pages of text created by copying a SO page and pasting into the new fresh document with **Paste Special...Unformatted Text**. I then draw some shapes - I've gotten similar results with rectangles, triangles, and ovals. No shapes are inline. I may ctrl-click some shapes to duplicate them. But every time, the first code block works perfectly: the top and bottom shapes on each page have a bold outline. Even if I move shapes around, when I run the code again only the top and bottom shapes on each page have a bold outline.

However, when I run the second code block I get erratic behavior. Sometimes the correct shapes are deleted. Sometimes they're not. I may draw or ctrl-click-copy shapes after running code, then run again, but I can't find a pattern to what makes the code stop working as expected. This occurs even when the shapes are not moved. In short, nothing but the code changes, yet it seems the `ShapeRange.Delete` method is acting in an unexpected way.

**The two sets of code**
Here's the code that changes the shape properties:

```
'---------find the first and last shape on each page, make bold-----------
Dim pg As Page
Dim shp As Variant
Dim shp_count As Long, maxt As Long, maxb As Long

'for each page
For Each pg In ActiveDocument.Windows(1).Panes(1).Pages

  'find the number of shapes
  shp_count = 0
  For Each shp In pg.Rectangles
    If shp.RectangleType = wdShapeRectangle Then shp_count = shp_count + 1
  Next

  'if there are more than 2 shapes on a page, there
  'are shapes to be made bold
  If shp_count > 2 Then

    'prime the maxt and maxb for comparison
    'by setting to the first shape
    For Each shp In pg.Rectangles
      If shp.RectangleType = wdShapeRectangle Then
        maxt = shp.Top
        maxb = maxt
        Exit For
      End If
    Next

    'set maxt and maxb
    For Each shp In pg.Rectangles
      If shp.RectangleType = wdShapeRectangle Then
        If shp.Top < maxt Then maxt = shp.Top
        If shp.Top > maxb Then maxb = shp.Top
      End If
    Next

    'Make top and bottom shapes bold outline
    For Each shp In pg.Rectangles
      If shp.RectangleType = wdShapeRectangle Then
        If shp.Top = maxt Or shp.Top = maxb Then
          shp.Range.ShapeRange.Line.Weight = 10
        Else
          shp.Range.ShapeRange.Line.Weight = 2
        End If
      End If
    Next

  End If
'go to next page
Next
```

And, if I modify the code such (only in the last For...Next loop, see the comment), different shapes are deleted, even leaving some shapes that have a line.weight = 10!

```
'---------find the first and last shape on each page, make bold-----------
Dim pg As Page
Dim shp As Variant
Dim shp_count As Long, maxt As Long, maxb As Long

'for each page
For Each pg In ActiveDocument.Windows(1).Panes(1).Pages

  'find the number of shapes
  shp_count = 0
  For Each shp In pg.Rectangles
    If shp.RectangleType = wdShapeRectangle Then shp_count = shp_count + 1
  Next

  'if there are more than 2 shapes on a page, there
  'are shapes to be made bold
  If shp_count > 2 Then

    'prime the maxt and maxb for comparison
    'by setting to the first shape
    For Each shp In pg.Rectangles
      If shp.RectangleType = wdShapeRectangle Then
        maxt = shp.Top
        maxb = maxt
        Exit For
      End If
    Next

    'set maxt and maxb
    For Each shp In pg.Rectangles
      If shp.RectangleType = wdShapeRectangle Then
        If shp.Top < maxt Then maxt = shp.Top
        If shp.Top > maxb Then maxb = shp.Top
      End If
    Next

    'Make top and bottom shapes bold outline
    For Each shp In pg.Rectangles
      If shp.RectangleType = wdShapeRectangle Then
        If shp.Top = maxt Or shp.Top = maxb Then
          'here's the modification, nothing else changed
          shp.Range.ShapeRange.Delete
          'shp.Range.ShapeRange.Line.Weight = 10
        Else
          shp.Range.ShapeRange.Line.Weight = 2
        End If
      End If
    Next

  End If
'go to next page
Next
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is most likely occurring because of the way that you are deleting your shapes.  When deleting items from a collection of objects in vba, you need to start with the last object and work your way toward the first object in the collection.  Your code:

```
For Each shp In pg.Rectangles
 ....
      shp.Range.ShapeRange.Delete
 ....
Next
```

should read:

```
For i = pg.Rectangles.Count to 1 Step -1

 ....
      pg.Rectangles(i).Delete
 ....
Next
```

This is necessary, because as soon as you delete the first object, the collection will re-index itself, and now the formerly 2nd object is the 1st object and so on.

Comment: Good point, but your code results in an error "Object doesn't support this property or method." on the line `shp = pg.Rectangles(i)`.

Comment: Yep, you're right.  I changed the code to something that should work now.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's some way to keep the collection of shapes from re-indexing itself. I noticed `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` doesn't keep this from happening.

Comment: @AaronThomas, you cannot stop the collection from re-indexing.  That behavior is designed into VBA.

Comment: I had to modify `pg.Rectangles(i).Delete` to `pg.Rectangles(i).Range.ShapeRange.Delete`, but looks like that is indeed the issue. Thank you for your help!