# Remove the chart object which is bookmarked

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, excel-2010

After so much work on VBA as a beginner, finally can copy the chart from excel to Word to a location which is bookmarked in word.
However, if I want to replace a new chart in same location when I refresh the code, the old chart in word is not deleted, hence the chart will be added on top of the old chart.

Is there any functionality in VBA code which can help me in deleting the old chart and add new chart in same bookmarked location ?

Below is the code which I wrote in excel to copy the chart from excel to word.

```
Sub Bookmarkchart()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
Set WordDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("F:\charts.doc")
Sheets("ToFilm").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart.CopyPicture _
Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
WordDoc.Bookmarks("testbookmark").Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, Placement:=wdFloatOverText, _
DisplayAsIcon:=False
WordDoc.Close
Set WordDoc = Nothing
Set objWord = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

How can I delete the chart from the word file and replace new chart.

Comment: I replicated lifeinvba's script and ended up with the same error 5342. I am wondering if it could be an issue with the clipboard that does not have time to get the picture before trying to paste it in Word? The script copies the picture "Chart 2" but appears to be unable to paste it at all (wdPasteMetafilePicture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name the picture after pasting in word:

```
Selection.Name = "MyPic"
```

At the beginning of your code you should then delete the latest version before pasting a new one:

```
WordDoc.Shapes("MyPic").Delete
```

Edit: Here is what the full code should look like. I haven't tested it so there may be one or two bugs to iron out.

```
Sub Bookmarkchart()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
Set WordDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("F:\charts.doc")
On Error Resume Next
WordDoc.Shapes("MyPic").Delete
On Error Goto 0
Sheets("ToFilm").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart.CopyPicture _
Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
WordDoc.Bookmarks("testbookmark").Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, Placement:=wdFloatOverText, _
DisplayAsIcon:=False
Selection.Name = "MyPic"
WordDoc.Close
Set WordDoc = Nothing
Set objWord = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: +1. Not sure if Word allows for duplicate shape names (PowerPoint does, and Excel I think does not in the worksheet scope, but does in the Workbook scope). If it does, and you are dealing with a large number of items, it's best to generate a large hexadecimal string as a unique ID.

Comment: Word does allow duplicate shape names, in fact, it doesn't care what you name them. It's the ID of the shape that matters... see my findings in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710959/ms-word-2010-macro-how-to-select-all-shapes-on-a-specific-page/18776373#18776373).

Comment: Hi Patrick, david and Aardvark thanks all of you for commenting on my post, as I know little bit of VBA, can anybody suggest me where to make the changes in the above code to delete the old shape (i.e. chart) and add new chart in the document, @Aardvark - I understood the flow of your code but I'am unable to fit the code in the above code..Please help me in adding the bit of code

Comment: @aardvark123 when i execute using f8 key, the cursor stops at the below code line WordDoc.Bookmarks("test").Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, Placement:=wdFloatOverText, _
DisplayAsIcon:=False                                              and throws an error " run time error '5342' - The specified data type is unavailable " . Kindly let me know is it due to Placement:=wdfloatovertest issue it should be changed to wdInline ?